# I need to print a variable from another class

Tags: flutter

hi everyone I need to print a variables from another class which are they bannerImageUrl and the profileImageUrl I saved them to the firebase storage and it is appears to the folders there but I want to print their url in one of the collection in the firebasefirestore .

this the UtilsService to upload the images to database

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;


class UtilsService {
  Future<String> uploadFile(File _image, String path) async {
    // refrence to upload an img
    firebase_storage.Reference storageReference =
        firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(path);

    firebase_storage.UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);

    await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    String returnURL = '';
    await storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
      returnURL = fileURL;
    });
    return returnURL;
  }
}
```

and this the UserService to save the images into the data base

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:insight_software/models/user.dart';
import 'package:insight_software/other_screen/UtlsService.dart';

class UserService {
  UtilsService _utilsService = UtilsService();

  List<UserModel?> _userListFromQuerySnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return UserModel(
        id: doc.id,
        name: doc.get("First Name:"),
        profileImageUrl: doc.get('profileImageUrl') ?? '',
        bannerImageUrl: doc.get('bannerImageUrl') ?? '',
        email: doc.get('email') ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  UserModel? _userFromFirebaseSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot != null
        ? UserModel(
            id: snapshot.id,
            name: snapshot.get("First Name:"),
            profileImageUrl: snapshot.get('profileImageUrl'),
            bannerImageUrl: snapshot.get('bannerImageUrl'),
            email: snapshot.get('email'),
          )
        : null;
  }

  Stream<UserModel?> getUserInfo(uid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_userFromFirebaseSnapshot);
  }

// save the images into the database
  Future<void> updateprofile(
      File _bannerImage, File _profileImage, String name) async {
    // track for the banner image and the profile image
    String bannerImageUrl = '';
    String profileImageUrl = '';

    if (_bannerImage != null) {
      bannerImageUrl = await _utilsService.uploadFile(_bannerImage,
          'Users/profile/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}/banner');
    }
    if (_profileImage != null) {
      profileImageUrl = await _utilsService.uploadFile(_profileImage,
          'Users/profile/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}/profileimg');
    }
    // UPLOADING THE BANNER IMAGE AND PROFILE IMAGE AND THE NAME TO DATABASE
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap();

    if (name != '') data['First Name'] = name;
    if (bannerImageUrl != '') data['bannerImageUrl'] = bannerImageUrl;
    if (profileImageUrl != '') data['profileImageUrl'] = profileImageUrl;

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .update(data);
  }
}
```

and the class that I want to print the variables URL is SignUppage2 it is too long but I will provide the part that I want to call the variables in

```
child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        Users.add({
                          'First Name': Fname,
                          'Last Name': Lname,
                          'user role ': value,
                          'user gender': value2,
                          'Nationality': value3,
                          'intersted Displiance': value4,
                          'intersted university': value5,
                          'email': _signupscr!.auth.currentUser?.email,
                          'bannerImageUrl': _userModel.bannerImageUrl,
                          'profileImageUrl': _userModel.profileImageUrl,
                        }).then((value) => print('user added')).catchError(
                            (error) => print('failed to add user:$error'));
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('sign up new account');
                      } else {
                        print("sign up failed");
                      }
                    },
```

how I can print the bannerImageURL and the profileImageurl in the SignUppage2??

what i add in the class it is print an empty string in the Firestore

Answer (score 0):

You can use `argument` parameter to pass data to another screen.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "sign up new account",arguments: {"bannerImageURL " : 
      _userModel.bannerImageUrl, "profileImageUrl": _userModel.profileImageUrl});
    },
```

And on SignUpPage2 you can get data in build method get as:

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final  Map<String, Object>rcvdData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    print("rcvd fdata ${rcvdData['profileImageUrl']}");
    print("rcvd fdata ${rcvdData['bannerImageURL ']}");

    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Second")),
      body: Container(child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text("Second"),
    ],),),);

}
```